# Translating date objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In the controller I have something like this:

```
  def methodfoo
    # set the profile attributes
    @start_date = Date.parse('June 24th, 2002')
    @college = 'University of Chicago'
    render :layout => 'profile'
  end
```

and in the YML file I added this:

```
 date:
    formats:
      default: "%Y-%d-%m"
      short: "%b %d"
      long: "%B %d, %Y"
```

And in the html.erb file I added the "t" function and used it like this:

```
<ul><li><%= t('.started') %> <%= t(@start_date) %></li></ul>
```

But it isn't working: It is not translating it.  What have I done wrong?

Comment: It's a small L, as in "localization".

Comment: Add the solution as an answer and accept it, please, so that in the future everyone with the same issue will find it right away :-)